# Getting data out of Native pointers

Tags: raku, nativecall

It's no big deal to get data into Perl 6 Native pointers:

```perl6
sub memcpy( Pointer[void] $source, Pointer[void] $destination, int32 $size ) is native { * };
my Blob $blob = Blob.new(0x22, 0x33);
my Pointer[void] $src-memcpy = nativecast(Pointer[void], $blob);
my Pointer[void] $dest-memcpy = malloc( 32 );
memcpy($src-memcpy,$dest-memcpy,2);
my Pointer[int] $inter = nativecast(Pointer[int], $dest-memcpy);
say $inter; # prints NativeCall::Types::Pointer[int]<0x4499560>
```

However, I see no way of getting them out of the `Pointer[int]` other than creating a function to do it, since [`nativecast`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/nativecast) apparently works in the opposite direction, or at least not in the direction of casting to non-native types (which should be obvious by its name). How would you do that?

*Update*: For instance, using an Array would make it more workable. However

```perl6
my $inter = nativecast(CArray[int16], $dest);
.say for $inter.list;
```

This works, but yields the error: `Don't know how many elements a C array returned from a library`

*Update 2*: Following [Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083251) (thanks!), we can ellaborate it a little bit more into this, and we get to put the values back into a [`Buf`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Buf)

```perl6
sub malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}
sub memcpy(Pointer $dest, Pointer $src, size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}

my $blob = Blob.new(0x22, 0x33);
my $src = nativecast(Pointer, $blob);
my $dest = malloc( $blob.bytes );
memcpy($dest, $src, $blob.bytes);
my $inter = nativecast(Pointer[int8], $dest);

my $cursor = $inter;

my Buf $new-blob .= new() ;
for 1..$blob.bytes {
    $new-blob.append: $cursor.deref;
    $cursor++;
}

say $new-blob;
```

We need to cast the pointer to exactly the same type used by the buffer, and then [we use pointer arithmetic](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Typed_Pointers) to run over it. However, we use `$blob.bytes` to know when to end the loop, and it's still kind of hacky. Would there be a more direct way? Or just a way of working with Bufs/Blobs so that they can be copied easily to the Native realm and back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NativeHelpers::Blob`](https://github.com/JJ/NativeHelpers-Blob):

```perl6
use NativeCall;
use NativeHelpers::Blob;

sub malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}
sub memcpy(Pointer $dest, Pointer $src, size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}

my $blob = Blob.new(0x22, 0x33);
my $src = nativecast(Pointer, $blob);
my $dest = malloc( $blob.bytes );
memcpy($dest, $src, $blob.bytes);
my $inter = nativecast(Pointer[int8], $dest);

my Blob $esponja = blob-from-pointer( $inter, :2elems, :type(Blob[int8]));
say $esponja;
```

This program [extends Christoph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081475/getting-data-out-of-native-pointers/51083251?s=3|0.0000#51083251) adding the `blob-from-pointer` function, which will return the original blob: `Blob[int8]:0x<22 33>`. This answer is also now [in the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#Buffers_and_blobs)

Answer (score 7):

Complete example:

```
use NativeCall;

sub malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}
sub memcpy(Pointer $dest, Pointer $src, size_t $size --> Pointer) is native {*}

my $blob = Blob.new(0x22, 0x33);
my $src = nativecast(Pointer, $blob);
my $dest = malloc(nativesizeof(int16));
memcpy($dest, $src, nativesizeof(int16));
my $inter = nativecast(Pointer[int16], $dest);
say $inter.deref.fmt('%x');
```

I assume you were looking for the `deref` method, but there were a few other issues with your code:

- use of `int32` instead of `size_t` in the declaration of `memcpy`
- wrong order of the arguments to `memcpy`, which means you were copying two bytes read from uninitialized memory into your supposedly immutable Blob
- use of plain `int` where you probably should have used a sized integer type such as `int16`

Also note the use of plain `Pointer` in the declaration of `memcpy`, which will allow you to pass in any pointer type without having to cast constantly.

Comment: Well, kinda, but `$inter` is still a `Pointer[int16]`, a native pointer, even if I can print it (for some reason, in reverse order)

Comment: Also, wouldn't that be `$blob.bytes` instead of `nativesizeof(int16)`? Thanks a lot for your answer, anyway.

Comment: @jjmerelo: the reverse order is due to [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) integer encoding; re your 2nd comment, I chose `nativesizeof(int16)` because it's arguably 'safer' to provide the size of the destination argument when possible; note that I assumed your goal was creating a 16-bit integer, not an arbitrary native blob