# Raku how to pass a pointer to a Buf to a native call for writing

Tags: raku, nativecall

I'm trying to wrap the `read` function from `unistd.h`, but can't get it to work.
Here's what I have: (in file: `read.raku`)

```
use NativeCall;

# ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
sub c_read(int32 $fd, Pointer $buf is rw, size_t $count --> ssize_t) is native is symbol('read') { * }

my $buf = Buf[byte].new(0 xx 5);
my $pbuf = nativecast(Pointer, $buf);
say c_read(3, $pbuf, 5);
say '---------------------';
say $buf;
```

I test it like this, from the command line (bash):

```sh
$ (exec 3< <(echo hello world); raku ./read.raku)
```

But I get:

```
5
---------------------
Buf[byte]:0x<00 00 00 00 00>
```

So it looks like the bytes read from FD 3 are not written to the `Buf`.

I also tried this instead:

```
use NativeCall;

# ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

sub c_read(int32 $fd, Pointer $buf is rw, size_t $count --> ssize_t) is native is symbol('read') { * }
sub c_malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native is symbol('malloc') { * }

my $pbuf = nativecast(Pointer[byte], c_malloc(5));

say c_read(3, $pbuf, 5);
say '---------------------';
say $pbuf[^5];
```

But I get a segmentation fault, I guess due to dereferencing into unauthorized memory location with `$pbuf[^5]`. But even just `$pbuf.deref` doesn't give the first byte read.

So I must have done something wrong or completely misunderstood how to work with native calls.

UPDATE:
After playing around with it more, it looks like the problem with the second snippet above is with the `is rw` bit. This seems to work:

```
use NativeCall;
use NativeHelpers::Blob;

sub c_read(int32 $fd, Pointer $buf, size_t $count --> ssize_t) is native is symbol('read') { * }

sub c_malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native is symbol('malloc') { * }
my $pbuf := nativecast(Pointer[byte], c_malloc(5));

say c_read(3, $pbuf, 5);
say '---------------------';
say $pbuf[^5];   # (104 101 108 108 111)
```

Comment: See also [NativeHelpers-Blob](https://github.com/salortiz/NativeHelpers-Blob)

Comment: cf SO [Getting data out of Native pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081475/getting-data-out-of-native-pointers) (for which the answer is to use `NativeHelpers-Blob`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so the problem is with the `rw` trait given to the `Pointer $buf`. I guess that results in the `read` function incrementing the pointer as it writes, and thus gives the wrong address when I use it later.

Here's the working code for both cases:

```
use NativeCall;

# ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

sub c_read(int32 $fd, Pointer $buf, size_t $count --> ssize_t) is native is symbol('read') { * }


# Passing a pointer to a Buf directly:
{
    my $buf = Buf[byte].new(0 xx 5);
    my $pbuf = nativecast(Pointer[byte], $buf);
    say c_read(3, $pbuf, 5);
    say '---------------------';
    say $buf;

}


# Using malloc also works:
{
    sub c_malloc(size_t $size --> Pointer) is native is symbol('malloc') { * }
    my $pbuf = nativecast(Pointer[byte], c_malloc(5));

    say c_read(3, $pbuf, 5);
    say '---------------------';
    say $pbuf[^5];
}
```

Tested it like this:

```
$ (exec 3< <(echo hello world); perl6  ./read.raku)
5
---------------------
Buf[byte]:0x<68 65 6C 6C 6F>
5
---------------------
(32 119 111 114 108)
```

Comment: oh I tried it but it didn't make a difference, and then I fixed the signature of my native sub and forgot to remove the `use NativeHelpers::Blob;` part. Using the correct signature (i.e., without the `is rw`) you don't need to `use NativeHelpers::Blob;`.